# otp tag confusion?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [otp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/otp) tag is intended to be used, according to its wiki description, for Erlang/OTP (Open Telephony Platform).

Many, many questions use it for one time passwords instead.

I'd suggest renaming [otp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/otp) to [erlang-otp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang-otp) (because, outside Elixir, there aren't many other languages that use OTP), but I'm not sure what to do about the one time password use.

*(yes, I know about LFE, JOXA, etc., which also run on BEAM and can use OTP)*

Comment: There's a [tag:one-time-password] tag you could use.

Comment: Is one-time-password really worth a tag?  It seems like a meta tag to me.

Comment: I thought this was going to be about shipping and [One True Pairings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_(fandom)#Notation_and_terminology).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan HTMLxRegex otp

Comment: Yet another case of [TLA](http://www.catb.org/esr/jargon/html/T/TLA.html) overload confusion.

Comment: I've been watching the `otp` tag for years now and correcting every new question I see that's supposed to be `one-time-password` or `opentripplanner`, etc. I just went through all the `otp` questions and retagged the few that snuck through. Can we rename the `otp` tag to `erlang-otp` instead now please? I would do it myself but I don't have the needed permissions.

Comment: Not to be confused with USB [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go).